# Does the browser 'WebSocket' work fine with Capacitor cross platform?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, cross-platform, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I want to open a Websocket as a client from an app. Currently I am writing it with React + [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/solution/react), usually capacitor has its own plugins (or allows you to use cordova plugins (but i am trying to steer clear of these since most have not been maintained in ages).
In this case there does exist a [plugin](https://github.com/mia-z/capacitor-websocket) but it is very small and I wouldn't want to use this plugin in production a critical system.

My question then: can I use the default websocket browser implementation freely and it will work fine in android/ios ? I know that for android something like cleartext might become an issue.

I tried the above mentioned plugin but it failed to react outright. The browser sockets work fine but then again I can't trust this fully and just testing it with some phone is not enough of a guarantee that it will work with any android/ios device.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some insights with Capacitor and WebSocket I've found (as of iOS 17 and Android 14).

iOS:
Worked fine for me with `ws`.

On Android:

- Make sure you're using the same security for **both**, the localhost web (your app) and the websocket. meaning: http**s** --> ws**s** or http --> ws. (this can be adjusted in the `capacitor.config.ts` under `androidScheme`.
- To support modern SDKs, make sure you add the clear text to the manifest (`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`)
  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/websocket-opening-handshake-was-canceled/212744 (or you'll might get unknown error without much details)